# How to add a token from localstorage to every POST request to /api router in workbox?

Tags: workbox

I use workbox for service worker in my app and I have no any idea how to accomplish this.

Is it possible with workbox or I should manually rewrite fetch handler in service worker?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith('/api/'),

    async ({ url, request, event, params }) => {
        const headers = {};
        for (var entry of request.headers.entries()) {
            headers[entry[0]] = entry[1];
        }

        const modifiedRequest = new Request(request, {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                token: 'token', // <-- put token here
            },
        });

        const response = await fetch(modifiedRequest);
        const responseBody = await response.text();

        return new Response(responseBody, {
            headers: response.headers,
        });
    },
    'POST',
);
```